# How to convert timestamp to days?

Tags: vue.js

I have my MySQL database inserting timestamp when I upload a record, so what's entered is something like 2020-04-02 16:59:29. Is there a Vue.Js way to convert that into something like 10 Days Ago? If so, can anyone give the code for conversion in Vue.Js?

I hold the fetched DB records in an object called data_local as in my bellow code.

**Last Activity :**  {{data_local.updated_at}} days ago

Comment: take a look at moment.js https://momentjs.com/

Comment: lookup vuejs filter, and moment or date-fns :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/2079271

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js, you can get your desired data the way you want. First do install moment and then import & use.

Below are ways to get days:

Ex-1:( This will provide you No_of_Days days ago ( e.g- 10 days ago)

```
moment("2020-04-02 16:59:29").fromNow()
```

Ex-2: (If you want only 10 days without ago then use below)

```
moment("2020-04-02 16:59:29").fromNow(true)
```

For more information visit https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks. The answer was useful.

Comment: What are all the possible ways that can be done when there is no timestamp entry in the table field, it is showing invalid date. Please help in this. @Dcoder

Comment: simple, do as `moment("2020-04-02", "YYYY-MM-DD")` then depending upon ur requirement you can followed by `format()` or `fromNow()`  @surhyanarayan

Comment: I cant understand what you are saying. Can you explain in detail.@Dcoder

Comment: what is ur requirement?

Comment: My timestamp fields will be a null value at times, when it is null, the above said method displays invalid date in my UI when the moment function is called. I dont want anything to be shown in this case or it may show any customized text, say date not available. @Dcoder